# Why doesn't tidyr:fill replace my NA values

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

`tidyr::fill()` isn't filling values in my tibble. Here is a reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(googlesheets4)

url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q5gdePANXci8enuiS4oHUJxcxC13d6bjMRSicakychE/edit#gid=1437767505"

gd_orig <- read_sheet(url) 

gd_orig %>%
  select(State, Date, matches("^Tests")) %>% 
  group_by(State, Date) %>%
  arrange(State, Date) %>%
  fill(`Tests conducted (negative)`,
       `Tests conducted (total)`, .direction = "down")
```

This produces:

```
# A tibble: 504 x 4
# Groups:   State, Date [455]
   State Date                `Tests conducted (negative)` `Tests conducted (total)`
   <chr> <dttm>                                     <dbl>                     <dbl>
 1 ACT   2020-03-12 00:00:00                           NA                        NA
 2 ACT   2020-03-13 00:00:00                           NA                        NA
 3 ACT   2020-03-14 00:00:00                           NA                        NA
 4 ACT   2020-03-16 00:00:00                           NA                        NA
 5 ACT   2020-03-18 00:00:00                           NA                        NA
 6 ACT   2020-03-18 00:00:00                           NA                        NA
 7 ACT   2020-03-19 00:00:00                         1853                      1857
 8 ACT   2020-03-20 00:00:00                         2056                        NA
 9 ACT   2020-03-21 00:00:00                         2212                      2221
10 ACT   2020-03-22 00:00:00                         2395                        NA
```

I expect the right-most column row 8 to have been replaced with 1857, and row 10 with 2221. What am I doing wrong that this isn't working?

Things I've tried that made no difference:

- renaming the columns to legal data.frame names eg `test_neg` and `test_tot`
- explicitly setting `.direction`

session info:

```
> devtools::session_info()
- Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
 os       Windows >= 8 x64            
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       Australia/Sydney            
 date     2020-05-02                  

- Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package       * version date       lib source                               
 askpass         1.1     2019-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 assertthat      0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 audio           0.1-7   2020-03-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 backports       1.1.6   2020-04-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 beepr         * 1.3     2018-06-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 broom           0.5.6   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 Cairo         * 1.5-12  2020-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 callr           3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 cellranger      1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 cli             2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 colorspace      1.4-1   2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 crayon          1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 curl            4.3     2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 DBI             1.1.0   2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 dbplyr          1.4.3   2020-04-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 desc            1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 devtools        2.3.0   2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 digest          0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 dplyr         * 0.8.5   2020-03-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 ellipsis        0.3.0   2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 evaluate        0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 extrafont     * 0.17    2014-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 extrafontdb     1.0     2012-06-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 fansi           0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 forcats       * 0.5.0   2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 frs           * 0.6.3   2020-04-25 [1] Github (ellisp/frs-r-package@6628329)
 fs              1.4.1   2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 gargle          0.4.0   2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 gdtools         0.2.2   2020-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 generics        0.0.2   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 ggplot2       * 3.3.0   2020-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 ggrepel       * 0.8.2   2020-03-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 glue            1.4.0   2020-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 googlesheets4 * 0.1.1   2020-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 gtable          0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 haven           2.2.0   2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 hms             0.5.3   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 htmltools       0.4.0   2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 httr            1.4.1   2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 jsonlite        1.6.1   2020-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 knitr           1.28    2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 lattice         0.20-41 2020-04-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 lifecycle       0.2.0   2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 lubridate       1.7.8   2020-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 magrittr        1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 memoise         1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 modelr          0.1.6   2020-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 munsell         0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 nlme            3.1-147 2020-04-13 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 openssl         1.4.1   2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 pillar          1.4.3   2019-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 pkgbuild        1.0.6   2019-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 pkgconfig       2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 pkgload         1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 prettyunits     1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 processx        3.4.2   2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 ps              1.3.2   2020-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 purrr         * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 R6              2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 Rcpp            1.0.4.6 2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 readr         * 1.3.1   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 readxl          1.3.1   2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 remotes         2.1.1   2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 reprex          0.3.0   2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 rlang           0.4.5   2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 rmarkdown     * 2.1     2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 rprojroot       1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 rstudioapi      0.11    2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 Rttf2pt1        1.3.8   2020-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 rvest           0.3.5   2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 scales        * 1.1.0   2019-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 sessioninfo     1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 showtext      * 0.7-1   2020-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 showtextdb    * 2.0     2017-09-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 stringi         1.4.6   2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 stringr       * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 svglite       * 1.2.3   2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 sysfonts      * 0.8     2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 systemfonts     0.2.0   2020-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 testthat        2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 tibble        * 3.0.1   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 tidyr         * 1.0.2   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 tidyselect      1.0.0   2020-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 tidyverse     * 1.3.0   2019-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 usethis         1.6.0   2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 utf8            1.1.4   2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 vctrs           0.2.4   2020-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 withr           2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 xfun            0.13    2020-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 xml2            1.3.2   2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                       
 yaml            2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
```

Comment: Not that it matters for the purpose of my question (now solved), but `fill()` is not satisfactory here anyway as a way of replacing those NA values; as that results in total tests being less than negative in many instances.

Comment: just came upon this because I have the same problem and I am using `fill()`.  I don't understand your rationale for saying that `fill()` is "not satisfactory here"?

Comment: I did get my script to work by removing the date from the `group_by` (from your answer below), but I as above, I don't understand why that works.  Care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the `.direction` to `downup` or `updown` as the output shows the `NA` are at the beginning and if we use "down" as option, it will fill the NA values with the preceding non-NA so the ones at the top remains as such because there are no preceding non-NA.  With 'downup', it will first do the fill in the downward direction that is filling NA with non-NA preceding, then does the reverse in upward i.e. filling NA with non-NA succeeding.  Also, with using 'Date' as one of the grouping columns, there are some groups with only NA and that would make the `fill` to return NA.  In this case, perhaps, we can group by only 'State'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gd_orig %>%
    select(State, Date, matches("^Tests")) %>% 
    group_by(State) %>%
    arrange(State, Date) %>%
    fill(`Tests conducted (negative)`,
          `Tests conducted (total)`, .direction = "downup")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Does it work for you? Perhaps it is a version thing. I will post my sessionInfo.

Comment: @PeterEllis i noticed that you are also grouping by 'Date' and if I use your data, some of them have only NA.  What would you expect for that.  I would remove the 'Date' from group_by

Comment: @PeterEllis your versions are correct.  It is the group by and .direction

Comment: Is there another circumstance in which this will not work?  I have a plain dataframe, and want to fill down character values.  No error, but also no filled values.  Ugh.

Comment: @Ben please check whether you have `NA` or `"NA"`

Comment: @akrun That was it.  Thanks!  I set my column to `NA`  like this:    `ifelse(column=="",NA,column)`   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I was grouping by date. So the NA had nothing to be replaced with.

Comment: it would have, but the `.direction` is a red herring. I will accept it as the answer now you've edited it to include the date.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your code without adding my email to tidyverse API but this should work. fill() takes the column to fill as an argument. A subset of a dataframe wouldnt work. Instead, add the column's index. Heres an example:

```
library(tidyr)
a <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA)
b <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, NA, 2)
c <- c(1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
tidyr::fill(df, 1:3, .direction = 'down')
```

Try something like this out!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33013888)